# Testing reading list from yaml file into list object

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot, yaml

I'm trying to load a list from application-test.yaml into the class, but it doesn't work.

This is how my **application-test.yaml** looks like:

```
category-merchandiser:
-
  username: test
  password: blas3cret
  roles:
    - test
    - admin
```

And this is my class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "category-merchandiser")
public class CategoryMerchandiserUsersConfig {

    private List<CategoryMerchandiser> users = new ArrayList<>();
    ** getters & setters **

    public static class CategoryMerchandiser {

        private String username;
        private String password;
        private List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    ** getters & setters **
```

This is how i'm trying to test if the size of my list is 2:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CategoryMerchandiserUsersConfig.class)
public class CategoryMerchandiserUsersTest {

    @Autowired
    CategoryMerchandiserUsersConfig config;

    @Test
    public void shouldLoadApplicationYamlToClass() {
        assertThat(config.getUsers().size(), is(2));
    }
}
```

My console output tells me that the list is empty:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <2>
     but: was <0>
Expected :is <2>

Actual   :<0>
```

What am i doing wrong? Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Anyone who can help? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works! My problem was that i've no application context. So i moved the tests into integration test directory. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your yml to match your config file it should work correctly.

```
category-merchandiser:
  users:
    - username: test
      password: blas3cret
      roles:
        - test
        - admin
```

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't work. Any other suggestion?

Comment: One issues as to why your test isn't working.

1. Your not loading any properties files @TestPropertySource. I'm not sure you can load a Yaml file. 

If you write and endpoint and return the data from CategoryMerchandiserUsersConfig.getUsers() it should work.